# c++ and global variables changed in functions

Tags: c++11, global-variables

I have these variable defined as global variables outside any function

```
//testing parameters (init to all nonfail)
int serverRandom = 0; //nonzero == fail > gotofail for first sha1 methode
SSLBuffer sigpar= 0; //nonzero == fail > gotofail for second sha1 methode
string hashOut = "nonfail"; //"fail" == error condition > gotofail for third sha1 methode
```

These variables are used in this function:

```
static OSStatus SSLVerifySignedServerKeyExchange(SSLContext *ctx, bool isRsa, SSLBuffer signedParams, uint8_t *signature, uint16_t signatureLen)
{
    OSStatus err;
    cout << "initval:"<< serverRandom<< signedParams<< hashOut<<endl;

    if ((err = SSLHashSHA1::update(&hashCtx, &serverRandom)) != 0)
        cout << "firstfail" <<endl;
        goto fail;
    if ((err = SSLHashSHA1::update(&hashCtx, &signedParams)) != 0)
        cout <<"secondfail"<<endl;
        goto fail;
        //goto fail;
    if ((err = SSLHashSHA1::final(&hashCtx, &hashOut)) != 0)
        cout << "thirdfail" << endl;
        goto fail;

    cout << "nonfail" << endl;

    fail:
        SSLFreeBuffer(&signedHashes);
        SSLFreeBuffer(&hashCtx);
        return err;
}
```

Note that the global variables ServerRandom and hashout are accessed directly in that function while the sigpar variable is given to the signedParams arguments of the sslVerify function.

Now, I wrote a unit test to test each failing case seperatly via this function

```
void unittest(){
    //all tests passing
    cout << "-------------nonfail-------------" << endl;
    result = SSLVerifySignedServerKeyExchange(&ctx,isrsa,sigpar,&sig,siglen);


    //first test fail
    cout << "-------------firstfail-------------" << endl;
    serverRandom = 1;
    result = SSLVerifySignedServerKeyExchange(&ctx,isrsa,sigpar,&sig,siglen);
    serverRandom = 0;

    //second test fail
    cout << "-------------secondfail-------------" << endl;
    sigpar= 1;
    result = SSLVerifySignedServerKeyExchange(&ctx,isrsa,sigpar,&sig,siglen);
    sigpar= 0;

    //third test fail
    cout << "-------------thirdfail-------------" << endl;
    hashOut = "fail";
    result = SSLVerifySignedServerKeyExchange(&ctx,isrsa,sigpar,&sig,siglen);
    hashOut = "nonfail";

}
```

Now it works perfectly for the first fail case eg. outputting the firstfail line. After that It does not work anymore as it just outputs the ---------secondfail-------- & ------thirdfail------- without outputting the failchecks (secondfail/thirdfail).

note that the initval inside sslverify...() shows the correct values, however the update/final function after the first testcause show 0 as a value for the respective values they recieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, it was easy to solve in the end:

in the SSLVerifySignedServerKeyExchange() I just forgot to add `{}` around the multi-line `if`'s after I added the `cout<<` so it would always goto fail after the first if